# In a recursive statment, how does java store the past values?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Factorial {
int factR(int n){
    int result;
    if(n==1)return 1;
    result=factR(n-1)*n;
    System.out.println("Recursion"+result);
    return result;
}
```

I know that this method will have the output of

```
  Recursion2
  Recursion6
  Recursion24
  Recursion120
  Recursive120
```

However, my question is how does java store the past values for the factorial? It also appears as if java decides to multiply the values from the bottom up. What is the process by which this occurs? It it due to how java stores memory in its stack?

Comment: `java store the past values for the factorial` in stack

Comment: [The call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

Comment: Also it's you who chose to print before returning ("bottom up"), not Java.

Comment: I suggest you step through this code in your debugger. This will show you the flow of execution, and all the values in the call stack. When you have a program and you don't understand what it is doing, the first thing you should try is the debugger in your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually isn't storing 'past values' at all. It stores the state of the program in the stack, with a frame for each method call containing data such as the current line the program is on. But there is only one value for the variable `result` at any time, for the current method on top of the stack. That gets returned and used to compute `result` in the frame that called this, and so on backwards, hence the bottom up behaviour you see.

One way to make this less confusing is to take recursion out of the picture temporarily. Suppose Java did not support recursion, and methods were only allowed to call other, different methods. If you wanted to still take a similar approach, one crude way would be to copy paste the `factR` method into multiple distinct but similar methods, something like:

```
int fact1(int n){
    int result;
    if(n==1)return 1;

    // Here's the difference: call the 'next' method
    result=fact2(n-1)*n;

    System.out.println("Recursion"+result);
    return result;
}
```

Similarly define a `fact2` which calls `fact3` and so on, although eventually you have to stop defining new methods and just hope that the last one doesn't get called. This would be a horrible program but it should be very obvious how it works as there's nothing magical. With some thought you can realise that `factR` is essentially doing the same thing. Then you can see that Java doesn't 'decide' to multiply the values bottom up: the observed behaviour is the only logical possibility given your code.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/

The values are stored on Java's call stack. It's in reverse because of how this recursive function is defined. You're getting n, then multiplying it by the value from the same function for n-1 and so on, and so on, until it reaches 1 and just returns 1 at that level. So, for 5, it would be 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1. Answer is the same regardless of the direction of multiplication.

You can see how this works by writing a program that will break the stack and give you a StackOverflowError. You cannot store infinite state on the call stack!

```
public class StackTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(1);
    }

    private static void run(int index) {
        System.out.println("Index: " + index);
        run(++index);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

well i am trying to understand you,

if someone call likewise then

`factR(3)` it's recursive process so obviously java uses Stack for maintaining work flow,

> NOTE : please see below procedural task step by step and again note
>   where it get back after current task complete.

```
result=factR(2)*3 // again call where n=2
    -> result=factR(1)*2 // again call where n=1
            -> now n=1 so that it will return 1

    -> result=1*2 // after return it will become 6
       print "Recursion2" // print remaning stuff
       return 2;
result=2*3 // after return it will become 6
print "Recursion3" // print remaning stuff
return 3
```

Comment: Got it so for every recursive process does java store all the values in the stack until recursion has ended?

Comment: If you write a recursive function that keeps infinitely nesting, then you get a StackOverflowError, hence the name of this web site :)

Comment: Exactly. That's what it SHOULD have. And why you get a StackOverflowError, if you don't. In other words, you end up with too much on the stack and it overflows. Which is where such an infinite recursion would go wrong by storing infinite values on the stack. Mentioning that here to illustrate that values cannot be stored on the stack infinitely. If you need to learn about it, you can look here: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/an-introduction-to-recursion-part-1/